# CosmosDb change feed processor with document with a wrong property value, how to handle?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a poison record in my CosmosDb which I read with a [Cosmos change feed processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor).
The poison record contains null in a property where there should be a value.
The problem is that I don't get an exception.

I want to log an error for this. What is the preferred way?

---

Instead of an exception, in the Debug output window, I see:

```
DocDBTrace Warning: 0 : Exception Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ChangeFeed.Exceptions.ObserverException: RequestUri: , 
    Exception has been thrown by the Observer.,    
    at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ChangeFeed.FeedProcessing.FeedProcessorCore`1.DispatchChangesAsync(ResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   ...
DocDBTrace Warning: 0 : Exception Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: RequestUri: , Error converting value {null} 
    to type 'System.DateTime'. Path 'Documents[0].Start', line 1, position 464.,    
    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   ...
```

The `Documents[0].Start` above is from my DTO

```
public class CustomerEntity{
    ...
    public DateTime Start {get; set;}
    ...
}

The setup is:
```

changeFeedProcessor = cosmosClient.GetContainer(...)
    .GetChangeFeedProcessorBuilder(..., searchSyncService.HandleChangesAsync)
        .WithLeaseConfiguration()
        ...
        .Build();

```
and the `HandleChangeAsync` is:
```

```
    internal async Task HandleChangesAsync(IReadOnlyCollection<CustomerEntity> changes, ...)
    {
        ...
    }
```

```
I have presently 2 possible solutions.  

The first is to catch the exception that is obviously thrown somewhere when the framework tries to deserialise to my CustomerEntity.  
The problem is that I don't know how.

The other solution is to call `GetChangeFeedProcessorBuilder` with `<object>` instead and deseralise the object myself.  
This is should be doable but is it the "correct" way?
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you put in the container/collection, documents that can have different schemas, you will get changes for any of them, so the class you use to read them should support all possible variations.

One possibility is to have your `CustomerEntity` class have:

```
[JsonProperty("Start", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
```

So then you can check `change.Start.HasValue`